# Tidyverse solution to grouping, and looping through dataframe to perform dunn.test

Tags: r, tidyverse, dunn.test, asbio

I have an example dataframe below.

```
example.df <- data.frame( 
species = sample(c("primate", "non-primate"), 50, replace = TRUE),
treated = sample(c("Yes", "No"), 50, replace = TRUE), 
gender = sample(c("male", "female"), 50, replace = TRUE), 
var1 = rnorm(50, 100, 5), resp=rnorm(50, 10,5), value1 = rnorm (50, 25, 5))
```

I want to group by `treated` first, and then loop over all numeric variables in the data to perform a dunn test (`pairw.kw` from the `asbio` package) using `species` as the explanatory variable, extract the `summary` dataframe object and bind the columns from the `yes` and `no` sub-lists into a new dataframe object.

I have already obtained a partial solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54878815/dplyr-dunn-test-error-in-dimrobj-cdx-dy-dims-product-0-do-not-matc) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54939785/loop-a-function-that-returns-a-list-over-variables-in-a-dataframe-grouped-by-ano) using a partially "tidy" approach which works quite well. I am just looking for a more elegant tidyverse solution in order to help me learn to be a better R user.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: This is the output I have from [the code in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54878815/dplyr-dunn-test-error-in-dimrobj-cdx-dy-dims-product-0-do-not-matc) the partially "tidy" solution.

```
structure(list(var1.Diff = structure(1:2, .Label = c("-7.05229", 
"-2.25"), class = "factor"), var1.Lower = structure(1:2, .Label = 
c("-13.23198", 
"-8.25114"), class = "factor"), var1.Upper = structure(1:2, .Label = 
c("-0.87259", 
"3.75114"), class = "factor"), var1.Decision = structure(1:2, .Label = 
 c("Reject H0", 
 "FTR H0"), class = "factor"), var1.Adj..P.value = structure(1:2, .Label = 
 c("0.025305", 
 "0.462433"), class = "factor"), resp.Diff = structure(1:2, .Label = 
 c("1.10458", 
 "0"), class = "factor"), resp.Lower = structure(1:2, .Label = c("-5.07512", 
 "-6.00114"), class = "factor"), resp.Upper = structure(1:2, .Label = 
 c("7.28427", 
 "6.00114"), class = "factor"), resp.Decision = structure(c(1L, 
 1L), .Label = "FTR H0", class = "factor"), resp.Adj..P.value = 
 structure(1:2, .Label = c("0.726092", 
 "1"), class = "factor"), effect.Diff = structure(1:2, .Label = 
 c("-1.27451", 
 "-0.5625"), class = "factor"), effect.Lower = structure(1:2, .Label = 
 c("-7.4542", 
 "-6.56364"), class = "factor"), effect.Upper = structure(1:2, .Label = 
 c("4.90518", 
 "5.43864"), class = "factor"), effect.Decision = structure(c(1L, 
 1L), .Label = "FTR H0", class = "factor"), effect.Adj..P.value = 
 structure(1:2, .Label = c("0.686047", 
 "0.85424"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("No", "Yes"), class = 
 "data.frame")
```

Comment: Well the `broom` package is great because it turns the results of statistical tests into data frames that you can then manipulate, but I know for a fact that it doesn't work on the output of the dunn test.

Comment: Yes. I can second that the `broom` package does not cover the dunn test results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update 2022/03/16**

The tidyverse has evolved and so should this solution.

```r
library("asbio")
#> Loading required package: tcltk
library("tidyverse")

# It is good practice to set the seed before simulating random data
# Otherwise we can't compare
set.seed(12345)

example.df <-
  tibble(
    species = sample(c("primate", "non-primate"), 50, replace = TRUE),
    treated = sample(c("Yes", "No"), 50, replace = TRUE),
    gender = sample(c("male", "female"), 50, replace = TRUE),
    var1 = rnorm(50, 100, 5), resp = rnorm(50, 10, 5), value1 = rnorm(50, 25, 5)
  ) %>%
  # Make sure species is a factor as required by `pair.kw`
  mutate(
    species = factor(species)
  )

example.df %>%
  # We want to perform the test separately for each group
  group_by(
    treated
  ) %>%
  group_modify(
    # Perform test and extract summary
    ~ pairw.kw(.x$var1, .x$species, conf = 0.95)$summary
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#> # Groups:   treated [2]
#>   treated Diff     Lower    Upper    Decision `Adj. P-value`
#>   <chr>   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>         
#> 1 No      -2.67949 -8.12299 2.76402  FTR H0   0.334663      
#> 2 Yes     4.07071  -2.98047 11.12188 FTR H0   0.257843
```

It is straightforward to extend this approach to run 6 tests, one for each combination of a treatment group and a response variable (`var1`, `value1` or `resp`). For example we can convert the tibble from wide format (three response columns) to narrow format (three responses stacked row-wise) and then proceed pretty much as above.

```r
responses <- c("value1", "var1", "resp")

example.df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    all_of(responses),
    names_to = "variable"
  ) %>%
  group_by(
    treated, variable
  ) %>%
  group_modify(
    ~ pairw.kw(.x$value, .x$species, conf = 0.95)$summary
  )
#> # A tibble: 6 × 7
#> # Groups:   treated, variable [6]
#>   treated variable Diff     Lower     Upper    Decision `Adj. P-value`
#>   <chr>   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>     <chr>    <chr>    <chr>         
#> 1 No      resp     -1.46154 -6.90505  3.98197  FTR H0   0.598725      
#> 2 No      value1   4.62821  -0.8153   10.07171 FTR H0   0.095632      
#> 3 No      var1     -2.67949 -8.12299  2.76402  FTR H0   0.334663      
#> 4 Yes     resp     3.75758  -3.2936   10.80875 FTR H0   0.29627       
#> 5 Yes     value1   -2.97475 -10.02592 4.07643  FTR H0   0.408311      
#> 6 Yes     var1     4.07071  -2.98047  11.12188 FTR H0   0.257843
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**Old solution**

Here is a *tidy* approach to running multiple tests simultaneously.

```r
library("asbio")
#> Loading required package: tcltk
library("tidyverse")

# It is good practice to set the seed before simulating random data
# Otherwise can't compare
set.seed(12345)

example.df <- tibble(
  species = sample(c("primate", "non-primate"), 50, replace = TRUE),
  treated = sample(c("Yes", "No"), 50, replace = TRUE),
  gender = sample(c("male", "female"), 50, replace = TRUE),
  var1 = rnorm(50, 100, 5), resp=rnorm(50, 10,5), value1 = rnorm (50, 25, 5)) %>%
  # Make sure species is a factor as required by `pair.kw`
  mutate(species = factor(species))

example.df %>%
  # Nest the data for each treatment group
  nest(- treated) %>%
  # Run the test on each treatment group
  mutate(test = map(data, ~ pairw.kw(.$var1, .$species, conf = 0.95))) %>%
  # There is no broom::tidy method for objects of class pairw
  # but we can extract the summary ourselves
  mutate(summary = map(test, pluck, "summary")) %>%
  # Cast all the factor columns in the summary table to character, to
  # avoid a warning about converting factors to characters.
  mutate(summary = map(summary, mutate_if, is.factor, as.character)) %>%
  unnest(summary)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 8
#>   treated data        test     Diff    Lower  Upper Decision `Adj. P-value`
#>   <chr>   <list>      <list>   <chr>   <chr>  <chr> <chr>    <chr>         
#> 1 No      <tibble [2~ <S3: pa~ -1.705~ -7.99~ 4.58~ FTR H0   0.595163      
#> 2 Yes     <tibble [2~ <S3: pa~ -1.145~ -6.45~ 4.16~ FTR H0   0.672655
```

It is straightforward to extend this approach to run 6 tests, one for each combination of a treatment group and a response variable (`var1`, `value1` or `resp`). For example we can convert the tibble from wide format (three response columns) to narrow format (three responses stacked rowwise) and then proceed pretty much as above.

```
example.df %>%
  # From wide format to narrow format
  gather(varname, y, value1, var1, resp) %>%
  # Nest the data for each treatment group and each variable
  nest(- treated, - varname) %>%
  # Run 6 tests = (number of treatments) * (number of response variables)
  mutate(test = map(data, ~ pairw.kw(.$y, .$species, conf = 0.95))) %>%
  # There is no broom::tidy method for objects of class pairw
  # but we can extract the summary ourselves
  mutate(summary = map(test, pluck, "summary")) %>%
  # Cast all the factor columns in the summary table to character, to
  # avoid a warning about converting factors to characters.
  mutate(summary = map(summary, mutate_if, is.factor, as.character)) %>%
  unnest(summary)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 9
#>   treated varname data    test   Diff   Lower Upper Decision `Adj. P-value`
#>   <chr>   <chr>   <list>  <list> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr>         
#> 1 No      value1  <tibbl~ <S3: ~ 3.127~ -3.1~ 9.41~ FTR H0   0.329969      
#> 2 Yes     value1  <tibbl~ <S3: ~ -1.33~ -6.65 3.97~ FTR H0   0.622065      
#> 3 No      var1    <tibbl~ <S3: ~ -1.70~ -7.9~ 4.58~ FTR H0   0.595163      
#> 4 Yes     var1    <tibbl~ <S3: ~ -1.14~ -6.4~ 4.16~ FTR H0   0.672655      
#> 5 No      resp    <tibbl~ <S3: ~ 1.421~ -4.8~ 7.71~ FTR H0   0.657905      
#> 6 Yes     resp    <tibbl~ <S3: ~ 1.145~ -4.1~ 6.45~ FTR H0   0.672655
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

And what if you want to be flexible about the number and the name of responses? Then specify a list of responses:

```
responses <- c("value1", "var1", "resp")
```

And use tidy evaluation in the `gather` statement as follows:

```
example.df %>%
  # From wide format to narrow format, with tidy evaluation
  gather(varname, y, !!!rlang::syms(responses))
  # Rest of computation here.....
```

Comment: Thanks. That solves the grouping and extracting the data to a tibble parts of my question, but how about looping over all the numeric variables using tidy methods?

Comment: You can add more nesting variables. It is actually not entirely clear to me what you mean by looping over all the numeric variables.

Comment: I was referring to whether it is possible to modify the code to run the dunn test for `resp` and `value1` in addition to `var1` in this example using just a single execution of the code.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand -- run three tests `pairw.kw(var1, species)` and `pairw.kw(value1, species)` and `pairw.kw(resp, species)`? Report results from three tests at the end? In three rows or in three columns?

Comment: Yes. I was thinking that it would be 6 rows (3 variables x 2 per variable as there are two groups, "yes" and "no" in this dataset).

Comment: I have edited the question to add `dput(res.df)` results as an example of the dataframe I am trying to get using the `tidy` approach.

Comment: Can you check, ideally without any tidy manipulations, that the p-values are computed correctly? I just realized that `example.df` is random and we didn't set the random seed, so it is difficult to compare results.

Comment: That is so neat! The values are the same as what they are without tidy manipulations. I came across another example converting to long format around here, but could not grasp how that would help. I could try to figure this out myself, but my actual data has more than 50 variables and I am trying to avoid typing them in one after the other in the `gather` step. Any suggestions?  Thanks for your rapid responses. You have been most helpful in explaining `tidyverse` mechanics.

Comment: You can use tidy evaluation for that, I've added an example at the end. As an aside, I learned about this general workflow from the "Many Models" section of the R for Data Science book https://r4ds.had.co.nz/.